# strtotime of today

Tags: php

Hallo, I want to find the difference between today and another date,

convert todays date into unix time format here

```
 <?php
    echo '1st one'.strtotime(date("d.m.Y")).'<br>';
    echo '2nd one'.strtotime(date("m.d.Y")).'<br>';
    ?>
```

The first echo is producing some value, but not the second one. What is the bug in it...please help..

Comment: strtotime is limited to few date formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) makes assumptions based on the [date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) you give it. For instance

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("d.m.Y"))) //=> "2010-09-27"
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("m.d.Y"))) //=> "1969-12-31"
```

Note that when given an invalid date, strtotime defaults to the timestamp for 1969-12-31 19:00:00, so when you end up with an unexpected date in 1969, you know you're working with an invalid date.

Because `strtotime` is looking for day.month.year when you use `.` as the delimiter, so it sees "9.27.2010" as the 9th day of the 27th month, which obviously doesn't exist.

However, if you change it to use `/` as the delimiter:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("d/m/Y"))) //=> "1969-12-31"
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("m/d/Y"))) //=> "2010-09-27"
```

In this case, `strtotime` expects dates in month/day/year format.

If you want to be safe, Y-m-d is generally a good format to use.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth pointing out that `strtotime()` does accept words like "today" as valid input, so you don't need to put a call to date() in there if all you want is today's date. You could just use `strtotime('today');`.

Come to think of it, a simple call to `time();` will get you the current time stamp too.

But to actually answer the question, you need to consider that `d.m.Y` and `m.d.Y` are ambiguous - if the day of the month is less than the 12th, it is impossible to tell which of those two date formats was intended. Therefore PHP only accepts one of them (I believe it uses m/d/Y if you have slashes, but for dots or dashes it assumes d-m-Y.

If you're using strtotime() internally for converting date formats, etc, there is almost certainly a better way to do it. But if you really need to do this, then use `'Y-m-d'` format, because it's much more universally reliable.

On the other hand, if you're accepting date input from your users and assuming that strtotime() will deal with anything thrown at it, then sadly you're wrong; strtotime() has some quite big limitations, of which you've found one. But there are a number of others. If you plan to use strtotime() for this sort of thing then you need to do additional processing as well. There may also be better options such as using a front-end Javascript date control to make it easier for your users without having to rely on strtotime() to work out what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does not consider `09.27.2010` to be a valid date...

You could check it like this:

```
<?php
// will return false (as defined by the docs)
echo var_dump(strtotime("09.27.2010"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function expects to be given a string containing a US English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp. US time format is : MM DD YYYY

Comment: Hallo Stewie, In my second echo i wanted to convert todays date into unix format. So i have used echo '2nd one'.strtotime(date("m.d.Y")).'<br>';  Which is in MM.DD:YYYY. WHich is in US date format. But still the echo is not outputting any value why?

Comment: @user453893 take a look at my answer. While *you* know what format you're giving, PHP has to guess, so has rules about what various date formats look like. When you use a dot as a delimiter, it takes it as d.m.Y.

Comment: if you use DD MM YY use a dash(-) or a dot (.) .. If you use US date format MM DD YYYY , use a slash (/)

Answer (score 0):

look here for the Information about which formats are valid http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php. But what do you mean with deference between 2 dates? You mean the Timespan between 2 dates?

```
echo (time() - strotime("- 2 days")) . " seconds difference";
```

Something like that?

Comment: I mean difference between today and a given date.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime would not take the d.m.y format. good way is Y-m-d